# find the max frequency per row in a matrix whith multiple max

Tags: r, max, frequency

i have a matrix like this:

```
mat=matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,
         4,4,4,4,4,3,5,6,
         3,3,5,5,6,8,0,9,
         1,1,1,1,1,4,5,6),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
print(mat)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    4
[2,]    4    4    4    4    4    3    5    6
[3,]    3    3    5    5    6    8    0    9
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    4    5    6
```

i would like to find out the number of the row of the matrix in which we can find objects with the max frequency, especially those which have more than one max.
in this case, i would like to obtein a new vector like this:

```
     [,1]
[1,] "1" 
[2,] "3"
```

or something similar. The focus is on the index of the row with more than one max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop over the rows.  Get the frequency of each unique element with `tabulate`, check whether it is equal to `max` value (`==`) and use `which` to get the numeric index.  This will return all the `max` value if there are ties.

```
lst <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) {x1 <- tabulate(x)
                 which(x1 == max(x1))
     })
```

If there are only a single `max` value per row, the output will be `vector` or else we get a `list` output.

If we need to extract the elements that have more than one `max`

```
lst[lengths(lst)>1]
```

Comment: I think you can also use **table(x)** instead tabulate(x)

Comment: @Learner Yes, I could use it, but `tabulate` is faster.

Comment: this works but how can i extract the rows in which i have more than one max?
the dataset i'm handling has a lot of rows and it's impossibile to me to check manually